# ValueError: Could not find a format to write the specified file in single-image mode

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, scikit-image, data-augmentation

I am trying to read an image using skimage package, then crop it and then save it.
Till cropping it works fine. While saving, it throws the below error

> ValueError: Could not find a format to write the specified file in
>   single-image mode

Below is my code. Any help is highly appreciated.
thanks

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import skimage
import dataloader
from utility import To_csv
path='D:\\beantech_Data\\objtect_detection'

def crop(img):
    return skimage.util.crop(img, ((0,500),(0,0),(0,0)))

images, boxes,  labels = dataloader.train_loader(path)

os.makedirs(os.path.join(path, 'train','cropped'), exist_ok=True)

for i in range(len(images)):
    croped_image = crop(images[i])
    skimage.io.imsave(os.path.join(path, 'train','cropped',f'img{str(i)}'), croped_image)
    box = boxes[i]
    To_csv(box, i,os.path.join(path, 'train','cropped'), Aug= True )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, no file format is given in the code i.e. (.png, .jpeg etc).

By correcting this line the code works fine-

```
skimage.io.imsave(os.path.join(path, 'train','cropped',f'img{str(i)}.png'), croped_image)
```

thanks